# Google App Engine Delete Post Put operation

Tags: api, google-app-engine, restful-url

I am trying to build REST API. (First Attempt)

for my Delete and Put

```
class DeletePost(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def delete(self):
    postKey = self.request.get('postKey')
    if(postKey != ""):
        db.delete(postKey)

    return
```

The above code is not working. In order to get it work, I have to change it to **def get(self):**

The Html is

```
<form action="/deletePost" method="delete" class="form-search">
   <div class="row-fluid">
   <legend>Title:</legend>
   <input type="text" name = "postKey" class="input-xxlarge span12" placeholder="briefly describle this event"><br>   
   <input type="submit" value="Post" class="btn btn-large btn-primary pull-right" type="button">

</form>
```

The error I got is

```
405 Method Not Allowed
The method GET is not allowed for this resource.
```

Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only GET and POST variables are allowed in the form method attribute.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html

In your case the browser sees method="delete", doesn't recognize the value and defaults to "get".